# df percent used mystery

Tags: python, bash, unix, filesystems

I'm confused about how the Unix `df` command arrives at the percentage used for a file system.  Here's a little script I wrote to run `df` and figure out the same information independently:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0 (Santiago)
$ cat dftest.py
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
import subprocess 

def reportUsage(label, total, free):
  used = total - free
  print "%s=%dK, used=%dK (%d%%)" % (label, free, used, used*100/total)

p = subprocess.Popen(["df", "-k", "."], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.stdout.read()
rc = p.wait()

stat = os.statvfs(".")
total = (stat.f_bsize * stat.f_blocks) / 1024
free = (stat.f_bsize * stat.f_bfree) / 1024
avail = (stat.f_bsize * stat.f_bavail) / 1024

print "Total=%dK" % total
reportUsage("Free", total, free)
reportUsage("Avail", total, avail)
$ ./dftest.py
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4             20158332   3930688  15203644  21% /home

Total=20158332K
Free=16227644K, used=3930688K (19%)
Avail=15203644K, used=4954688K (24%)
$
```

So the total bytes, available space (unprivledged) matches, and used space (based on free space) all match.  Wonderful!  So how come `df` is reporting 21% used?  I think it should be reporting 19% since that's how much was used.  What am I missing?  This isn't just a rounding error, is it??

Comment: Quick google search `http://larsmichelsen.com/open-source/answer-why-does-df-k-show-wrong-percentage-usage/`

Comment: @Jidder Your link does not work.

Comment: @Lu.nemec seems to be adding two characters after `percentage`, don't know why, i think it worked when i first posted. Anyway just delete them from the url and it goes to the right place.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is because that in your case your file system occupies 1024000 (20158332-3930688-15203644) blocks, then `df` command reports the usage percentage as (1024000+3930688) / 20158332 = 24%. In you python code, you just calculate the usage percentage as 3930688 / 20158332 = 19%.

Comment: Yes, I knew about the 1024000KB - that's the difference between f_bfree and f_bavail.

Comment: (1024000+3930688) / 20158332.0 = 0.2457885900480258

Comment: what is the format of your file system? can you paste the output here of the command `df -k`

Comment: The output from df is in my original post.  It does not show the format.  When I look at the output from the mount command, it tells me it's ext4.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what `zhujs` commented, the reason for that difference is the reserved space allocated during file system creation. You can run the following to see the reserved space and your fs block size

```
$ sudo tune2fs  -l /dev/sda4 | grep -iE  'reserved block count|block size'
```

It depends on your fs, but I guess output on your system looks like this

```
Reserved block count:     256000
Block size:               4096
```

And that indicates 1024000 1K blocks are reserved. `df` reports this under *used space* since reserved space is not available for normal users.

Answer (score 0):

`total`, `free`, and `avail` are all being computed using integer, not floating-point, division. Try

```
total = (stat.f_bsize * stat.f_blocks) / 1024.0
```

which forces floating point division. Compare

```
>>> 9 / 2
4
>>> 9 / 2.0
4.5
```

(This is only an issue in Python 2 when not using `from __future__ import division`.)

Comment: This has nothing to do with rounding, it is using 19%

Comment: I agree, Jidder.  I changed the script anyway and it doesn't really help.